# Application Not Responding while reading Inbox Messages on Android App Start

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I'm using Marketing Cloud SDK (Mobile Push) v6.1.0
But I'm receiving a lot of ANRs as observed on Google Play Store performance reports.
ANR is observed while we are reading InboxMessages using following API during app start:-

```
MarketingCloudSDK.getInstance().getInboxMessageManager().getMessages()
```

ANR Stacktrace :-

```
"main" tid=1 Runnable 
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x71474d98 self=0x723f1ff000
  | sysTid=22382 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7240751ed0
  | state=R schedstat=( 28831282988 8928373669 6515 ) utm=2720 stm=161 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7ffe4fa000-0x7ffe4fc000 stackSize=8192KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  #00  pc 0000000000412794  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+140)
  #01  pc 00000000004f9c5c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+508)
  #02  pc 000000000051429c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+812)
  #03  pc 00000000004fa98c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::RunCheckpointFunction()+176)
  #04  pc 00000000005922a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JniMethodFastEndWithReference(_jobject*, unsigned int, art::Thread*)+68)
  at java.lang.Throwable.nativeFillInStackTrace (Native method)
  at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace (Throwable.java:799)
- locked <0x0e99555f> (a java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  at java.lang.Throwable.<init> (Throwable.java:277)
  at java.lang.Exception.<init> (Exception.java:66)
  at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init> (RuntimeException.java:62)
  at java.lang.IllegalStateException.<init> (IllegalStateException.java:55)
  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox.InboxMessage$Media.create (unavailable)
  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.c.a (unavailable)
  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.c.b (unavailable)
  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.c.a (unavailable)
  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox.d.getMessages (unavailable)
  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox.c.getMessages (unavailable)
  at com.example.myapp.common.notification.MyNotificationHelper.getInboxMessages (MyNotificationHelper.kt:227)
  at com.example.myapp.common.notification.MyNotificationHelper.getUnreadMessageCount (MyNotificationHelper.kt:36)
  at com.example.myapp.common.notification.MyNotificationHelper.updateNotificationBadgeCount (MyNotificationHelper.kt:54)
  at com.example.myapp.MyApplication.onCreate (GBClosetApplication.java:127)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1189)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6460)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:219)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1859)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved as of version 6.2.2 of the SDK.  Please update to at least that version or greater.  Current is 6.3.4 as of 2019-09-25.

Something else of note in your question; `getInstance()` is a thread blocking call.  It is probably a better idea to use `requestSdk()` in almost every imaginable scenario.  This will almost certainly resolve your issue as well.

Comment: Issue still persist in 6.3.4. We uploaded app to play store 2 days back, and I received 1 ANR with same stacktrace on my latest app version

Comment: `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url) && TextUtils.isEmpty(altText)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid media provided.");
}`
Based on the error you're receiving I suspect either the URL is invalid and there is no AltText for your message.  This is thrown in the InboxMessage.Media.create() method.

Comment: I'm not sure, which url you are talking about. But one more thing I suspected that I'm registering to Marketing Cloud SDK and fetching Inbox Messages at the same time. Since registration is asynchronous, it might be possible getInboxMessages() get blocked till registration.

Comment: It is 100% blocked until registration is complete and, as I noted, you should be using `requestSdk()` as opposed to `getInstance()`.  I assumed you already made that change.